# Realistic Effects of extreme isolation on a Pre Reformation Christian Community

Tags: religion

So I’m currently working on a fantasy story that features dimension hoping as a major setting element with infrequent jumps causing ideas to sometimes travel between worlds.

Anyway the idea in question is Christianity, but it’s Pre Reformation Christianity (So Catholic) that’s been left to stew in a world with no strong central authority and a less than dominate position compared to other religions.

What kind of details do I need to be aware of in Pre Reformation Christianity that are likely mutation points in Theology?

Comment: You should look at the church of Ethiopia for a real world example.

Answer (score 2):

**Almost any theological idea is a mutation point** as any theological or philosophical system is susceptible to evolution, just like biological systems, even such ideas about the definition of Good and Evil.

Note: I'm not familiar with Catholicism so my answer will be as general as possible while applying what Catholic thought I know. That said, I'll a dress the three main areas I know about.

Dogma - mutation in matters of dogma are unlikely to change. As Catholicism is an extremely conservative organization, change of any kind is slow. On matters of core faith is doesn't change at all.

Doctrine - Given that doctrine isn't nailed down as tightly as dogma, mutation in this area is more likely though the degree of mutation is likely to still be small.

Ordinances - This I'm less sure about. The interpretation of a particular ordinance may change through the physical act itself may not change at all. Although baptism of infants doesn't seem to [have any basis](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/886-what-is-the-history-of-infant-sprinkling) in the New Testament but is nonetheless an established practice in Catholicism.

Mutation is likely to result from the influence of a highly influential intellectual such as St. Francis of Assisi or a niche/fringe interpretation that somehow supercedes the prevailing interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue isn't going to be in the dimension that the Church is resident in, but how the characters interact with the Church (particularly in terms of running afoul of local religious customs).

There were lots of different Churches in the past, many of which had branched out from the Holy land and became established in out of the way places until the arrival of Catholic missionaries. The Cathars, Nestorians, Mandaeans, Eastern Orthodox and so on all have different (often radically different) interpretations of the Christian religion, so any church which has developed in isolation will certainly have a much different idea of how the Christian religion is interpreted.

In terms of how your Church is going to evolve, perhaps looking at the history of the Church will identify the possible points where mutations and changes could occur. Certainly one of the main points would be the First Council of Nicaea in 325 AD, where many of the ideas of Christianity were codified. If different ideas were adopted then, the resulting Church would be much different as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the history of the ["Hidden Christians"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Christians_of_Japan) or ["Kakure Kirishitan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakure_Kirishitan), those Japanese Catholics who continued to practise their faith in secret when the Tokugawa Shogunate persecuted Christianity.

Because of the necessity for secrecy they could only pass on knowledge of their religion, scriptures, prayers and so on by word of mouth from parent to child. Many changes came into their beliefs as a result. They forgot the meaning of Latin prayers, and the Catholic doctrines became merged with ideas from the surrounding Shinto and Buddhist religions.

I'm afraid I can't immediately find a source that describes these accretions and changes in any detail. In any case, it may be that the changes would be more accurately described as simply forgetting doctrine rather than the sort of intellectual changes in theology you are searching for. Nonetheless it is a real life example of Catholicism evolving in isolation.